# Problem when using extension in a XML Schema

Tags: xml, schema

I need to create a XML schema which extends simple types, so I could add an attribute for later use in my code (this attribute won't be used in the generated XML). It must be an extension since I have to estabilish some restrictions to these types.

Problem: msg_1 and msg_2 must have some elements with the same name and it's causing an error.

Error: cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_msg'. Multiple elements with name 'Code', with different types, appear in the model group.

I'm aware that making these element names different would solve the problem, but they must be the same, unfortunatelly.

Here's the code:

```
<xsd:element name="msg">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:group ref="header"/>    
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:group ref="msg_1"/>
                <xsd:group ref="msg_2"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="IdMsg" type="IdM" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:group id="M39" name="msg_1">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="Code">
                        <xsd:attribute name="compact" use="prohibited"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ID">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="ID">
                        <xsd:attribute name="compact" use="prohibited"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
<xsd:group id="M40" name="msg_2">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="Code">
                        <xsd:attribute name="compact" use="prohibited"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ID">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="ID">
                        <xsd:attribute name="compact" use="prohibited"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>

<xsd:simpleType name="IdM">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedByte">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="29"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="42"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ID">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedByte">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="255"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="Code">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedByte">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="13"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:group id="M2" name="header">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element fixed="2" name="Version" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
        <xsd:element name="Timer" type="xsd:unsignedLong"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

Is there any workaround?

Update:
Assertions are not the case. Basically, I have two different messages(groups) sharing some parameters(child elements).

I guess that namespaces could do the trick, but I'm trying to avoid it, since it's preferrable to have only 1 .xsd file.

I get the part about ambiguity and etc, but it doesn't answer why the code that follows validates just fine. Here's the code:

```
<xsd:element name="msg">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:group ref="header"/>    
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:group ref="msg_1"/>
                <xsd:group ref="msg_2"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="IdMsg" type="IdM" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:group id="M39" name="msg_1">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="anything" type="code"/>
        <xsd:element name="something_else" type="code"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
<xsd:group id="M40" name="msg_2">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="nothing" type="code"/>
        <xsd:element name="something_else" type="code"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>

<xsd:simpleType name="code">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedByte">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="IdM">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedByte">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="29"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="42"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>


<xsd:group id="M2" name="header">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element fixed="2" name="Version" type="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
        <xsd:element name="Timer" type="xsd:unsignedLong"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

Curiously, it works even with 2 elements sharing the same name (something_else). If the elements named "anything" and "nothing" are taken out of msg_1 and msg_2, the issue about ambiguity returns. Is there any explanation about it? I see no reason for this behavior, so I must be missing something.

PS: The code here is just an example, and I know the 2 groups are exactly the same. I made the code to ilustrate the problem. In my application the groups are different even though they share some elements.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is designed so that when a particular element is encountered by the validator, the validator knows without ambiguity where to find the rules for that element, based solely on its name (and the type of the containing element). Your schema clearly violates that rule: when a `Code` is encountered, there are two possible definitions and it won't know which one to choose.

If you're trying to write an XSD for an existing class of XML documents where the rules are context-sensitive, then you may be able to express the constraints in a different way, for example using XSD 1.1 assertions, or using Schematron.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I just updated the question with some more info. Unfortunatelly assertions are not the case here.